# Input element of type="file" not activated after click event

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the SELECT A FILE button on my UI, it does not allow me to upload a file as I expect it to.

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

Here is the HTML portion of the button:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 15px">
  <input type="file" id="input-file" hidden="hidden">
  <button type="button" id="select-a-file-custom-button">SELECT A FILE</button>
  <span id="custom-text">No file chosen yet!</span>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript that is meant to activate the button:

```
// Step 1: Load file
selectFileBtnCtm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selectFileBtn.click();
});

selectFileBtn.addEventListener('change', e => {

    selectFileBtnCtm.innerHTML = "FILE LOADED"
    customTxt.innerHTML = e.target.value;
    hashBtnTxt.innerHTML = "Ready to hash!"; 
    hashBtn.id = 'custom-button';

});
```

In case you need to see all files in the directory, [click here](https://github.com/jmartinez-43/byonotary).

Comment: Try without `hidden="hidden"`?

Comment: How do you define `selectFileBtn`?

Comment: make sure you have no other error in the console.  On seeing your code, looks like on line 158 in `app.js`, `web3` is not initialized because, you are doing it on `load` event. So when executing 158, it throws an error. You should move these lines(158, 159) too inside the load event or find a better place.

Comment: you can't hide it completely. you can make it opacity:0 and stretch it to fit over your other buttons, to catch their clicks.

Comment: @Panther Thank you, that solved my problem. I needed to include lines 158 and 159 inside the load event. How do I credit you with the correct answer?